# Pushing to the next view also shifts present view to the left

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, pushviewcontroller

When i am presenting next view using push from the right then the present view is also getting shifted to left.

I guess this is the default functionality. But how should can I stop present view controller from moving left.

[image] 
As shown in the image, the new view controller is presented from left and previous view controller moves to left.

How should can I stop the present view controller from moving left.

Comment: This is, indeed, the default behavior of `UINavigationController`. You *can* create your own custom animation, but consider that this is the animation the user expects when navigating horizontally in an iOS app; this is familiar to them.

Comment: Actually i want to stop the present view animation which is going left.

Comment: is it possible ?

Comment: You only want to slide the new view on top of the already present view, right?

Comment: Yes. Only new view animate from right. present view will stay as it is.

Comment: is there any luck to do the same ?